# how to create ajax preloader

Tags: jquery, ajax

I know this is a bit of noob question but i will just throw it.

```
$('#loading')
.ajaxStart(function () {
    $(this).show();
}).ajaxStop(function () {
    $(this).hide();
})
```

I have this code in my .js, and have

```
<div id="loading"><img></div>
```

inside my html.

and i have a layer that loads ajax when click on the button.

```
jQuery(document.body).on('click', '.open_list', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
jQuery(".ajax_list").fadeOut(function () {

jQuery('.list').addClass('slideIn');
    var $ajaxList = jQuery(this);

    $ajaxList.load("http://lifeto.dothome.co.kr/xe/free .ajax_contents", function () {
        $ajaxList.fadeIn();
    });
});
});
```

the question is, how do i load the preloader div (#loading) inside of the .list when it's loading data?

i am only a beginner at jquery and ajax, so i have no idea what $(this) and .ajaxStart refers to.

here is the actual address of my website.
http://lifeto.dothome.co.kr/xe/page_FIsv96

Comment: Just read the docs about these two methods: [`ajaxStart`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) [`ajaxStop`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/). Both links provide the examples of what can be performed inside the handlers. You also can debug these handlers, to see the actual value of `this` (I think it will be `window` object)

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<a href="#" id="verification" >test</a>
<img src="example_preloader.gif" id="ajaxPreloader" style="display:none" />
```

JS

```
$('#verification').click(function() {
    $('#ajaxPreloader').toggle();
    $.ajax({
       type     : "POST",
       url      : "example url",
       data     : {'exampleData': ''},
       success : function(msg) {
        $('#ajaxPreloader').text('');
        location.reload();
       },
       error:    function(error) {
        $('#ajaxPreloader').text('');
       }
    });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work-

```
$(document)
.ajaxStart(function () {
    $('#loading').show();
}).ajaxStop(function () {
    $('#loading').hide();
})
```